How to combine the multiple collections as a collection in geometry node?
I wonder how to combine the multiple collections as a new collection for instancing them on points in Geometry Nodes.
For example, I have 3 selected collections and want to random array them on a spline. I know we can make it easier by putting all unit objects into one collection but this way will not be effective anymore when you have more than 50 unit groups that need to be separated to collaborate with other nodes and some of them need to combine for nodes like this.
This will be very helpful to me for adding new future collections or changing to another combination option using the Switch Index Node.

I tried to combine them using "Geometry to Instance Node" but they made the overlapping at the collections that have multiple unit objects like Group A and B.
You can take a look at my example file (Blender 4.3 Version).


Just a simple recommendation: objects can be linked to multiple collections. Let's say you have a blue cube, a red cube, a blue sphere and a red sphere. Then you can make a collection "blue" which holds blue cube and blue sphere, collection "red" for red cube and red sphere, collection "cubes" for blue and red cube, collection "spheres" for blue and red sphere and a collection "all" which has all four objects. This way each collection can be used separately in Geometry Nodes but you can work on "all" as well.

@GordonBrinkmann How do you do that ? I've seen something similar in the doc concerning collections, I don't quite understand the process. Sorry if it's something obvious. Are you talking about GN, or about the outliner ?

From https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html#collections-menu: Link to Collection Shift-M :
Add selected objects to a collection, while keeping them in their current collection. This way objects can appear in multiple collections. A new collection can be created in the pop-up.

Amazing, thank you monseigneur !

Gordon, the linked objects for the combination collections work well when you just want some specific options. But it is not a good idea if you want a lot of random options. Maybe with more than 100 options of the combination then you have to create 100 collections manually, I guess. Not to mention that you add the new future unit objects and more options as well. So, Markus von Broady's answer below is the solution for this. Thank you for your advise.

@EricNguyen Never said it was a perfect solution, otherwise I would have written an answer. Some people are just not aware it is possible to have objects in multiple collections (see comments above). Also I never said you have to create collections for all combinations, that was just an example. As I understood the question you already have objects in different collections for different purposes and want to keep them. So my suggestion would have been now to create just one more collection, select all objects from the other collections and link them to the new one to work on them together.

It looks like you want to realize your instances with depth of 1:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
With this setup I don't see z-fighting of various colors, also text doesn't overlap.

Great, Markus von Broady . This is exactly what I want for the combination options. Thank you.
